# How best to do this specific row operation in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, pivot

So for this task, in my real data set. I have 18 rows that are indcode = 000000 and ownership code = 10. The differentiating factor is area. Likewise, I have 18 rows that are indcode = 4911 and ownership code = 10. Sample data below narrows it to 4 for easy computing. Some context.. in my real data set, I have monthly data hence the year (02) and Month (Jan) from 02-Jan to 23-Jun. The 910 is the new indcode.. it represents total federal employment in a given area and time. Federal employment is defined as indcode = 000000 subtract indcode = 4911. the indcode = 55 is just to make it more realistic.

PS, I am having some difficulty with the "02-Jan" so feel free to rename it as Jan. Just trying to keep it in line with the real product.

```
 indcode <- c("000000","000000","000000","000000", "55", "4911","4911","4911","4911")
 ownership <- c("10","10","10","10","10","10","10","10","10")
 area <- c("000000","031","029","017","029","000000","031","029","017")
 "02-Jan" <- c(1000,600,300,100,50,100,50,40,10)
 "02-Feb" <- c(1003,601,301,101,51,101,51,41,11)

  first <- data.frame(indcode, ownership, area, `02-Jan`, `02-Feb`)
```

so for each area, here is an example. the actual 02 values would not be 1000-100 but rather 900 but I thought that this would make it clearer.

```
    indcode    ownership    area     02-Jan    02-Feb
      910          10        000000    1000-100     1003-101  
      910          10        031       600-50       601-51
```

Comment: This question is currently hard to follow. "I have 18 rows" and then your example data has 9 rows. "910 is the new indcode" but that's not in the example data. `area` cycles through 4 values twice and one value once, but you only want two of those values in the output? Unclear how your desired output comes from the example data. What action do you want to perform?

Comment: @ Jon Spring, in my real life data set, I have 18 apiece but trimmed it down for the example. The output would have 4 rows.. I just typed out 2 to make it fast. The four comes from there being 4 areas in common between the two industries

Comment: It's usually best to share data using `dput`, especially when there are naming issues such as here. Please add the output from `dput(first[1:10,1:8])` (or whatever number of rows/columns needed to demonstrate your point).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
first |>
  summarize(across(3:4, ~max(.)-min(.)), 
  # OLD: summarize(across(3:4, ~paste(rev(range(.)), collapse = "-")), 
            .by = area) |>
    #"3:4" refers to the 3rd and 4th column once we set aside the area grouping
    # We could alternated specify the columns by name, e.g. X02.Jan:X02.Feb
  mutate(indcode = 910, ownership = 10, .before = 1)
```

Result

```
  indcode ownership   area X02.Jan X02.Feb
1     910        10 000000     900     902
2     910        10    031     550     550
3     910        10    029     260     260
4     910        10    017      90      90
```

Comment: Valiant attempt at mimicking the OP's vacant `indcode`/etc values

Comment: @Jon Spring.. how would I change it if I wanted the x02.Jan value in the first row to be 900?

Comment: Updated, thank you for clarifying what you meant.